# Structure: Include files that is needed

Tags: php, structure

In a new project I am thinking to separate some functionality in their own individual file thus I need to include them when needed. For example database object would have a file where it's initiated. I would have a 'session' file for handling all session initialization (session_start() hijack check and so forth) This would lead to me only needing to include files that is needed.

**Is this a maintainable approach? Does it make any sense to separate all this functionality in different files and only requiring them when needed?**

For example on a static 'About' page I would not need the db file thus I wouldn't include the db file. I am on a time limit and I am not very deeply motivated to get started with MVC but I would like to keep a structure that still is maintainable and would not cause any problem with future performance. I am using php thus the php tag.

One file could look like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'session.php';
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'db.php';

//...
```

Mean while another would only have this:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

//...
```

And so on.

Answer (score 2):

Perfectly acceptable to my eyes.

And maintainable as long as your code is well commented and clean of course. Make sure to keep the order of imports right, since maybe including the database one before the session one, will make the later to stop working for example.

It makes more sense than having duplicated code everywhere if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is good practice to separate such functionality as you have done so. This make the code more maintainable and easier to correct bugs.

What may be of interest to you is the autoload feature that was added in PHP5. This may make it easier http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php